# Circle movements clock and anti-clockwise in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-animation

I am working on an Android application in which I have two concentric circles with the text at center. I have used drawable for both circles. I want to rotate both circle in counter clockwise to each other, i.e. one in clockwise and other in anti clockwise direction.

My code is given below for anim folders along activity code and snap for explanation.

[image]

progress_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

progress_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="0" />
```

My Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/red_theme"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
        android:text="Stop" />


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_imageLeft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/halfcircle"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_imageRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/halfcircle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="MUry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Beige"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My code at activity

```
Animation animRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    R.anim.progress_right);
            animRight.setDuration(1000);
            mImageRight.startAnimation(animRight);

            Animation animLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                    R.anim.progress_left);
            animLeft.setDuration(1000);
            mLLLeft.startAnimation(animLeft);
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your relative layout with Image view and check the following updated code:

```
        private ImageView mImageLeft, mImageRight, mImageProfile;
        private ImageView mLLLeft;
        mLLLeft = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_imageLeft1);
        mImageRight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_imageRight);

        Animation animRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.progress_right);
        animRight.setDuration(1000);
        mImageRight.startAnimation(animRight);
        Animation animLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.progress_left);
        animLeft.setDuration(1000);
        mLLLeft.startAnimation(animLeft);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if it will work, but just try to set `android:toDegrees="-360"` in progress_right.xml.

Comment: this works for me. Rotation is now counterclockwise, thanx

Answer (score 1):

Just add one ImageView to your xml and remove Relative layout movement. Your text is moving because you have put your relative layout to the animation and your text is inside the layout.Updated xml code is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/red_theme"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:text="Start" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="67dp"
        android:text="Stop" />


    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_imageLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/halfcircle"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_imageLeft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/halfcircle" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_imageRight"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/halfcircle" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="MUry"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Beige"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnStop"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```